# IntelliJ Plugin Development - Parameter / Method Hints

Tags: intellij-plugin

I am looking into writing plugin for the IntelliJ IDE for testing. I would like methods and classes to have something to indicate the number of tests and coverage they have. i.e. I have a method in my class and I can see that it has 3 tests written for it and 50% coverage.

I want this to be done without editing the code at all, almost exactly like how parameter hints work.

My problem is that I am fairly new to this and after reading the documentation I am struggling to see if an interface like this is even possible?  Is there a way of doing this? Is there a better way of doing this?

Many Thanks,
James

Answer (score 0):

I'd use codeInsight.lineMarkerProvider extension for this.
Implementing LineMarkerProvider interface allows to show an interactive icon on left gutter. It's the extension used to "Has implementations" icon etc.